# QBO API Add Payment error

Tags: php, api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm connecting to Quicbooks using IPP_V3 from my webserver.

I'm trying to implement the `example_payment_add.php`

I'm getting a Business validation error when adding payment by assigning it to an invoice.

I even changed the order in which the values are assigned as instructed in the below page:

> https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/payment

*(Last point: The sequence in which the Lines are received is the sequence in which lines are preserved.)*

*Note: Just adding a payment to a customer, without assigning it to a customer, is working.*

> Error:
>   6000: [A business validation error has occurred while processing your request, Business Validation Error: Unexpected Internal Error. (-30035)]

Code:

```
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/header.tpl.php';

    ?>

    <pre>

    <?php

    // Set up the IPP instance
    $IPP = new QuickBooks_IPP($dsn);

    // Get our OAuth credentials from the database
    $creds = $IntuitAnywhere->load($the_username, $the_tenant);

    // Tell the framework to load some data from the OAuth store
    $IPP->authMode(
QuickBooks_IPP::AUTHMODE_OAUTH, 
$the_username, 
$creds);

    // Print the credentials we're using
    //print_r($creds);

    // This is our current realm
    $realm = $creds['qb_realm'];

    // Load the OAuth information from the database
    if ($Context = $IPP->context())
    {
// Set the IPP version to v3 
$IPP->version(QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::VERSION_3);

$PaymentService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Payment();

// Create payment object
$Payment = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Payment();


$Payment->setTxnDate('2014-04-04');


// Create line for payment (this details what it's applied to)
$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setAmount(1);

// The line has a LinkedTxn node which links to the actual invoice
$LinkedTxn = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_LinkedTxn();
$LinkedTxn->setTxnId('10001'); //real invoice number in quickbooks
$LinkedTxn->setTxnType('Invoice');

$Line->setLinkedTxn($LinkedTxn);

$Payment->addLine($Line);

$Payment->setCustomerRef('876');
    $Payment->setPaymentRefNum('8762393');
    $Payment->setTotalAmt(1);

// Send payment to QBO 
if ($resp = $PaymentService->add($Context, $realm, $Payment))
{
    print('Our new Payment ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
}
else
{
    print($PaymentService->lastError());
}

/*
print('<br><br><br><br>');
print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
print('Request [' . $IPP->lastRequest() . ']');
print("\n\n\n\n");
print('Response [' . $IPP->lastResponse() . ']');
print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
*/  
    }
    else
    {
die('Unable to load a context...?');
    }


    ?>

    </pre>

    <?php

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/footer.tpl.php';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly incorrect:

> $LinkedTxn->setTxnId('10001'); //real invoice number in quickbooks

You should be using the Id value from the invoice in QuickBooks. The Id value is *different from* the user-visible Invoice reference # (the DocNumber field).

You need to use the Id value.

This also doesn't make a whole lot of sense:

> $Line->setAmount(1);
>
> ...
>
> $Payment->setTotalAmt(0.01);

How can the total payment amount be only 1 penny, and then you try to apply a full dollar to the invoice?

Comment: Thanks, Keith! Fixed the amount difference which was an oversight.

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED: Need to use Transaction Id of the Invoice instead of the Invoice Number.

Comment: Is there any way I can use Invoice Number instead of Transaction Id?

Comment: No, you need to use the Id # whenever referencing customers, invoices, payments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using a httpSnooper tool(like fiddler) or by enabling the devkit logger, you should try to capture the raw request and response XML/JSON.

You can use the XML/JSON in ApiExplorer tool to debug this issue.

Otherwise, you can try to create a payment from QBO ui and retrieve the same using GetById endpoint. That way you can find out the correct structure of the payment object.

Hope it will useful.

Thanks

Comment: There's no need for that. He can get the raw request/response by just calling print($IPP->lastRequest()); and print($IPP->lastResponse());